# converting LLVM IR to other language code

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to convert LLVM IR into C like language (we can say toy C language) having grammar similar to C with some new keywords. I know I have to write a long code for doing this. But I do not how to proceed?

Can anyone guide me for the same? Or is some tutorial sort of thing is available, so that I can take help from it.

Thanks in Advance

**Update1**

I have come across a link explaining to [build LLVM IR for Kaleidoscope](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl7.html)  if i can get a tutorial converting this IR back into code, it will give a lot of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is overly broad. This is a large task, and you should be more specific about which part of the task you're seeking help with. Here are some pointers to existing projects you may want to look at:

1. The LLVM C backend - generates C code back from LLVM IR. The caveat is that this backend was dropped following the 3.1 release so you'll have to look in the [sources of earlier releases](http://llvm.org/releases/index.html).
2. [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) - generates Javascript from LLVM IR

Comment: can you also provide some link which can explain the LLVM C backend

Comment: @Arpit: there is no such link AFAIK. There may be comments in the code, though.

Comment: LLVM C backend gave me a lot of help. Now the question how to compile and run this file as for, writing a compiler for converting a language to LLVM IR we run the command `clang++ -g toy.cpp` ``llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native`` `-o toy.cpp` so what to do in here??

Comment: @Arpit: not sure what you're asking exactly. I suggest you open a new question where you explain in detail what you want to achieve, what you tried that did not work, etc. The more details you provide, the higher the chance you get a good answer.

Comment: What I want is to write some thing like c backend and use it. I have written the code and I want to know how to use that in generating the desire output.